# Copying and renaming date in file name + 7 days. (PowerShell)

Tags: excel, powershell, date

I have a folder of spreadsheets which all start with "WEEK COMM" and then the date. For example "WEEK COMM 24-12-2018". What I am looking to do is a script that finds the latest file, makes a copy of it in the SAME folder, and changes the date in the filename by adding 7 days.

So far I have got this, which successfully locates the most up to date file, and copies it as "WEEK COMM TEST", but I am unable to find anything about adding a date to the filename.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "\\DESKTOP-88SIUP6\Users\User\Desktop\Shared\STOCK ORDERS\2018" |
    Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 1 |
    Copy-Item -Destination "\\DESKTOP-88SIUP6\Users\User\Desktop\Shared\STOCK ORDERS\2018\WEEK COMM TEST.xlsx" -Force
```

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will capture the string date from the file `.BaseName` property, convert it to a `[datetime]` object, add 7 days, convert that to a date string in your [backwards [*grin*]] format, and then replace the old date string with the new date string in the `.FullName` of the file.

that should make the rename process pretty direct & easy. [*grin*]

if you can, you would likely have a rather easier time if you switched to the more logical, properly sortable `yyyy-MM-dd` format. you may not be able to do so, but it's worth trying ...

```
$FileName = [System.IO.FileInfo]'WEEK COMM 24-12-2018.xlsx'

$FN_StringDate = $FileName.BaseName.Split(' ')[2]
$FN_Date = [datetime]::ParseExact($FN_StringDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy', $Null)

$NewFN_StringDate = $FN_Date.AddDays(7).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')
$NewFileName = $FileName.FullName -replace $FN_StringDate, $NewFN_StringDate

$FileName.FullName
$NewFileName
```

output [old, then new] ...

```
D:\Data\Scripts\WEEK COMM 24-12-2018.xlsx
D:\Data\Scripts\WEEK COMM 31-12-2018.xlsx
```

---

edit to add a very specific example. it's untested since i haven't any such location ... that is why the `-WhatIf` is there. [*grin*]

```
$SourceDir = '\\DESKTOP-88SIUP6\Users\User\Desktop\Shared\STOCK ORDERS\2018'
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir |
    Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 1 |
    ForEach-Object {
        $FN_StringDate = $_.BaseName.Split(' ')[2]
        $FN_Date = [datetime]::ParseExact($FN_StringDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy', $Null)

        $NewFN_StringDate = $FN_Date.AddDays(7).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')
        $NewFileName = $_.FullName -replace $FN_StringDate, $NewFN_StringDate

        # remove the "-WhatIf" when you are ready to do this for real
        Copy-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $NewFileName -WhatIf
        }
```

Comment: Hi Lee, this would work but if I'm reading it correctly, would require me to specify the file name each time in the first line? I already have a script that will find the latest file and copy that one, so can I incorporate your script into that? Instead of declaring the file name each time?

Comment: @shadowthr0ne - put the code in your loop by adding a `ForEach-Object` just after the `Select-Object`. the S-O cmdlet will be sending you the file info, so you can use that to generate the new file name, and then use that new file name in the `Copy-Item` command.

Comment: Sorry Lee, I am very new to PowerShell so having some trouble with this. Which code do I need to put after ForEach-Object. Do I need to start the code with brackets? Do I actually need $FileName = [System.IO.FileInfo]'WEEK COMM 24-12-2018.xlsx' in the code?

Comment: the 1st line just creates a fake file name to use to demo the ideas involved. so leave that out. the last two lines are there to show the original and new file names that resulted from the lines before them ... again, leave that out. ///// i will add a `ForEach-Object` section to my demo so you can see it.

Comment: Lee, you are a genius. This worked PERFECTLY! Exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: @shadowthr0ne - you are most welcome! i'm glad to have helped ... [*grin*]